# How to search a string in another string?

Tags: java, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to see if a substring exists inside another string in Java 1.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687577/how-to-see-if-a-substring-exists-inside-another-string-in-java-1-4)

How would I search for a string in another string?

This is an example of what I'm talking about:

```
String word = "cat";
String text = "The cat is on the table";
Boolean found;

found = findInString(word, text); //this method is what I want to know
```

If the string "word" is in the string "text", the method "findInString(String, String)" returns true else it returns false.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

That is already in the String class:

```
String word = "cat";
String text = "The cat is on the table";
Boolean found;

found = text.contains(word);
```

Answer (score 21):

Use the `String.indexOf(String str)` method.

From the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29):

> Returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the
>   specified substring.
>
> ...
>
> **Returns:** if the string argument occurs as a substring within this
>   object, then the index of the first character of the first such
>   substring is returned; if it does not occur as a substring, -1 is
>   returned.

So:

```
boolean findInString(word, text)
{
  return text.indexOf(word) > -1;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`word.contains(text)`

Take a look at the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29).

> Returns true if and only if this string contains the specified
>   sequence of char values.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by using

```
boolean isContains = text.contains(word);
```

Answer (score 0):

`found = text.contains(word);`