# Checking whether a group of contiguous sub strings in present in a string Java

Tags: java, string

Suppose i have 2 strings:

```
String1 = "I love dogs and cats"
String2 = "love dogs"
```

and i want to find if string1 contains string2. How do i do it ??

Thanks and regards

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Looks like homework that sould be done by OP itself

Comment: Look at `String`'s methods. Your question has the correct keyword.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to search a string in another string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9276040/how-to-search-a-string-in-another-string)

Answer (score 0):

The String java API has a method that does what you want. This method is `contains()`. Here is how to use it :

```
String str1 = "I love dogs and cats";
String str2 = "love dogs";

boolean isIn = str1.contains(str2); // isIn = true.
boolean isIn = str1.contains("love cats"); // isIn = false
```