# How do I find the presence of a given word in a Java String?

Tags: java, string

> **Please see also:**
>   [How to see if a substring exists inside another string in Java 1.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687577/how-to-see-if-a-substring-exists-inside-another-string-in-java-1-4)
>   [Searching for one string in another string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940114/searching-for-one-string-in-another-string)
>   [How to search a string in another string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9276040/how-to-search-a-string-in-another-string)

I have two strings, like so:

```
String str1 = "He is doing very good";
String str2 = "doing";
```

I want to know how to find the word "doing" in string `str1`, even if `str1` is changed like so:

```
str1 = "He isdoing very good";
```

Comment: Check the docs before asking a question. This is as basic as it gets.

Comment: Check the docs or Google... https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+find+string+in+another+string+in+java&oq=how+to+find+string+in+another+string+in+java

Comment: Or even just search the previous SO questions.  I found this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940114/searching-for-one-string-in-another-string and many more.

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way would be

```
str1.contains(str2);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about the [String.contains](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) method?